# How to install a package in development mode within conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, setup.py

Hello I have a conda environment that contains the following:

```yaml
name: bookassignment
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - ca-certificates=2021.10.8=ha878542_0
  - certifi=2021.10.8=py37h89c1867_1
  - click=8.0.4=py37h89c1867_0
  - colorama=0.4.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - importlib-metadata=4.11.2=py37h89c1867_0
  - ipython=7.31.1=py37h06a4308_0
  - jedi=0.18.1=py37h06a4308_1
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=h7274673_9
  - libedit=3.1.20210910=h7f8727e_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=hf484d3e_1007
  - libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libgomp=9.3.0=h5101ec6_17
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.3.0=hd4cf53a_17
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.2=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - ncurses=6.3=h7f8727e_2
  - openssl=1.1.1m=h7f8727e_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  - pip=21.2.2=py37h06a4308_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.20=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - pygments=2.11.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - python=3.7.6=h0371630_2
  - python_abi=3.7=2_cp37m
  - readline=7.0=h7b6447c_5
  - setuptools=58.0.4=py37h06a4308_0
  - shellingham=1.4.0=pyh44b312d_0
  - sqlite=3.33.0=h62c20be_0
  - tk=8.6.11=h1ccaba5_0
  - traitlets=5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - typer=0.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.1.1=pyha770c72_0
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - wheel=0.37.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - zipp=3.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7f8727e_4
prefix: /home/user/miniconda3/envs/bookassignment
```

I would like to install my existing project as a package in development mode within my conda environment by running `python setup.py develop`. The thing is that I'm new to packaging and I'm a bit lost on how to create `setup.py` containing all the information of my conda environment(dependencies, name, etc...).

Once you install `conda-build`, conda comes in with a command called `conda develop` which is supposed to do the exact same thing I describe above, but according to what I read it has not seen any development lately.
I'm trying to figure out the best way to have a properly setup package within my environemt that allows me to keep developing and reflect new changes.

Any help is very welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `but according to what I read it has not seen any development lately`, make sure you are reading the right resources. The [official github](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst) has its last release listed as 25th of January 2022, so quite recent I would say

Comment: I know that `conda-build` is up to date but I'm talking about [conda-develop](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-develop.html)